# When I print URL using retrofit call.request().url() it prints different URL

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a URL 
http://ec2-13-58-192-11.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/FCLContainer?filter=%7B%22where%22%3A%20%7B%22carrier%22%3A%20%22resource%3Aorg.shipping.bitnautic.Carrier%23carrier0%40carrier.com%22%7D%7D

But when I print URL in my logcat window after passing in retrofit and call the method call.request().url()
It prints this
http://ec2-13-58-192-11.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/FCLContainer?filter=%257B%2522where%2522%253A%2520%257B%2522carrier%2522%253A%2520%2522resource%253Aorg.shipping.bitnautic.Carrier%2523carrier0%2540carrier.com%2522%257D%257D%0A%0A

How can I handle this url?

Comment: once try with volley and simply print URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are giving encoded url to retrofit ,hence it reencoding url and showing you different .

Set url in Retrofit as Simple String ,in your case

http://ec2-13-58-192-11.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/FCLContainer?filter={"where": {"carrier": "resource:org.shipping.bitnautic.Carrier#carrier0@carrier.com"}}

In Retrofit log you will see as endcoded url

http://ec2-13-58-192-11.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/FCLContainer?filter=%7B%22where%22%3A%20%7B%22carrier%22%3A%20%22resource%3Aorg.shipping.bitnautic.Carrier%23carrier0%40carrier.com%22%7D%7D

Comment: Yes you are right.but now problem is in the carrier email(carrier0@carrier.com) is dynamic.Then how i attached dynamic string because in the url it convert again to the encoded format when i used + to concate dynamic email it did not give me correct response.Can you write me the how i write url with the email is dynamic

Comment: you can use @URL as parameter in you api service function ,also follow this link for reference ..
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests